# Memory limit set to -1 is the good approach?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, memory, memory-leak

In one of my custom script a memory exhaust issue showing.so i did set memory_limit to -1 now it is working fine.But is this the good approach to do this or need to increase the size of memory_limit variable on server?

Comment: Change the memory_limit variable on the server file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per memory management on server, we should increase the size of a `memory_limit` variable. because putting `memory_limit = -1` in particular page is consuming to much cpu process as well it also impacts on website performance when user ratio is increased on site.

So my point of view it needs to change server variable.

Comment: I have query here,if we set to -1 then this set memory with no limit.It should work like that it will occupy the memory whatever is needed on run time?

Comment: Yes that's right so let's take an example if your server has 1024 mb space and your page need 1000 it will take so remaining is only 24. So when other user access other page it's only 24 mb remain

Comment: ok can you tell me when we will set memory_limit=-1 then on above example,how it will impact ?

Comment: As i have write down in answer, just for testing purpose you can add memory_limit = -1, otherwise you need alternate solution for it, cause it's impacting on your website performance in load time.